# Calling an asynchronous function within a for loop typescript and nhibernate deadlock

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript, asp.net-web-api, nhibernate

I am writing an http post call inside a for loop with typescript.

While debugging the method in the backend, I noticed that he treats the requests simultaneously.

For example, let's say the server must run 2 methods `M1()` then `M2()` per single request. For the test case with n = 2. The server executes `M1()` for request 1, `M1()` for request 2, then `M2()` for request 2 and finally `M2()` for request 2.

Then after the `_session.commit()` an exception is thrown in the method intercept. the exception description is:

> NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException: 'Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect): [Server.Model.Identity.ApplicationRole#3]'

Code:

```
public calculate(index?: number): void {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.policy.coverages.length; i++) {
        this.callCalculate(i);
    }
}

public callCalculate(i: number): void {
    this.premiumCalculationParams = this.policy.createPremiumCalculationParams();

    if (!this.premiums) {
        this.premiums = new Array(this.policy.coverages.length);
    }

    this.offerService.calculatePremiums(this.policy, i).then((result: any) => {

        this.premiums[i] = new Array<Premium>();
        this.surpremiums = new Array<PremiumResult>();

        if (result.data && result.data.premiumTable && result.data.premiumTable.premiumPayment && result.data.premiumTable.premiumPayment.premiums && result.data.premiumTable.premiumPayment.premiums.length > 0) {
            _.each(result.data.premiumTable.premiumPayment.premiums, (premiumValue: any) => {
                let premium: Premium = new Premium();
                premium.setPremium(premiumValue);
                this.premiums[i].push(premium);
                this.policy.getCoverage(i).premiumPayment.premiums = angular.copy(this.premiums[i]);
            });

            if (result.data && result.data.results && result.data.results.length > 0) {
                _.each(result.data.results, (premiumValuel: any) => {
                    let sp = new PremiumResult();
                    sp.setPremiumResult(premiumValuel);
                    sp.premiums = new Array<Premium>();
                    _.each(premiumValuel.premiums, (premiumValue: any) => {
                        let premium: Premium = new Premium();
                        premium.setPremium(premiumValue);
                        sp.premiums.push(premium);
                    });
                    this.surpremiums.push(sp);
                });
            }

            console.log(this.surpremiums);
        }

        if (result.data && result.data.premiumTable && result.data.premiumTable.messageList && result.data.premiumTable.messageList.messages && result.data.premiumTable.messageList.messages.length > 0) {
            _.each(result.data.premiumTable.messageList.messages, (message: any) => {
                let messageType: any = MessageType[message.messageLevel.toString()];
                this.messages.push(new Message(messageType, "premiums", message.messageContent, this.premiums[i]));
            });

        }

    }, (err: any) => {
        this.premiums[i] = null;
        this.surpremiums = null;
        if (err && err.data && err.data.modelState) {
            for (var key in err.data.modelState) {
                var model = err.data.modelState[key];
                _.each(model, (state: string) => {
                    this.$log.debug(OfferControllerPrefix, "Calculation failed: " + state);
                });
            }
        }

        this.messages.push(new Message(MessageType.SVR_ERROR, "premiumCalculationParams", this.jsTranslations.getTranslation(Constants.DEFAULT_ERROR_NL), this.policy));
    });

}
public calculatePremiums(policy: Policy, selectedCoverageIndex : number): any {
    var uri = this.uriService.buildURI("Policy/Calculate");
    var data = {
        'policy': policy,
        'selectedCoverageIndex': selectedCoverageIndex
    };
    return this.$http.post<any>(uri, data);
}
```

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: You are trying to update a `Policy` that has already been updated. You need to go through your code and NOT do that.

Comment: Where are `M1` and `M2`? What is the POST inside `calculatePremiums`?  Is it  `M1` or `M2`?

Comment: Yes, after the http post call, there are many methods that run. By way of illustration, let's say there are two methods M1 () and M2 () in the backend server.

Comment: In the question, there is one function that returns a promise. Two other functions return `void`. Those two functions need to return promises if you intend to chain from them. The `.then` method of promise returns a new promise that yield the value returned to it.

Answer (score 0):

To chain two asynchronous operations, return values to their `.then` methods:

```
function M1(data) {
    return $http.post(url1, data);
}

function M2(data) {
    return $http.post(url2, data);
}
```

Chain the two functions like so:

```
function M1M2 () {

    var promise = M1(data);

    var promise2 = promise.then(function(data) {
       var data2 = fn(data);
       var m2Promise = M2(data2);
       return m2Promise;
    });

    return promise2;
}
```

Because calling the `.then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises.

It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.

For more information, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference - chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).